# Math equation with Graphic Tablet

Tags: gratis, graphs, math

I have a Graphic Tablet and I am looking for a software which have the following features:

**Math equation recognition**
I want to solve math equations in Graphic Tablet and auto recognized to copy paste them in a word processor like MS Word

**Live graph painting**
I want to plot graphs with different colors in the tablet and see them live in display to copy paste them in a word precessor like MS Word

In short, I have a lot (lot lot) equations in notes and I want to move them in digital form. Writing on MS Word is time consuming and I was wondering if there is a software that could make it easier with a Graphic Tablet.

I am interested on a free software, but if there is any really nice paid one, I could think about it.

Edit: I found this Web Service [MyScript](http://www.myscript.com/) which recognize the handwriting part from Graphic Tablet and translate to Latex or MathML. Exactly what I would like to do. But it is not a free service. Do you know any alternative to this one which may be free?

Comment: The myscript iOS apps are free if you have an iOS device and are willing to input the equations into an iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Onenote (as of 2010, I believe) is packaged with [Ink to Math](http://flisser.com/draw-math-equations-in-onenote/). The guy whose site I linked you to, myself, and some of my friends found it easy to use. Since you're looking for pasting into MS Word, that will be the easiest way to do it. Then, from there, [solving and graphing should hopefully be simple](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26364/solve-and-graph-equations-in-word-and-onenote/). I haven't tested that part, so I apologize if it's not what you're looking for.

Personally, I'm looking for a free LaTeX version, and I will add an answer if I find that.

Comment: Does the OneNote encompass advanced symbols - like partial differentials, integrals, etc.? Every example I see seems to have only basic trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

Infty Editor is an old tool for this which does the Math Equation aspect:

http://www.inftyproject.org/en/software.html